# How to show all tables that have specific number of records

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

is there a way to show all tables that have a specific number of records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm

Quick and dirty way:

`sp_MSForeachtable 'select ''?'' tblName, count(*) from ? where count(*) = X'`

This should only output those rows with X records

Answer (score 2):

For near 100% accuracy:

```
select object_schema_name(object_id) as schema_name, 
    object_name(object_id) as object_name,
    sum(p.rows)
from sys.partitions p
where index_id in (1,0)
group by object_id
having sum(p.rows) = @numberOfRows;
```

For true 100% accuracy, you must `COUNT(*)` from a cursor

Comment: +1 For accuracy comment.  Meta-data is fast but may not be correct!

Answer (score 1):

[This post](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/01/10/sql-server-query-to-find-number-rows-columns-bytesize-for-each-table-in-the-current-database-find-biggest-table-in-database/) has a nice query to do just that (as well as number of columns and row sizes):

```
USE DatabaseName
GO

CREATE TABLE #temp (
       table_name sysname ,
       row_count INT,
       reserved_size VARCHAR(50),
       data_size VARCHAR(50),
       index_size VARCHAR(50),
       unused_size VARCHAR(50))

SET NOCOUNT ON

INSERT #temp
EXEC sp_msforeachtable 'sp_spaceused ''?'''

SELECT a.table_name,
       a.row_count,
       COUNT(*) AS col_count,
       a.data_size
FROM #temp a
INNER JOIN information_schema.columns b
      ON a.table_name collate database_default = b.table_name collate database_default
GROUP BY a.table_name, a.row_count, a.data_size
ORDER BY CAST(REPLACE(a.data_size, ' KB', '') AS integer) DESC

DROP TABLE #temp
```

Answer (score 1):

COUNT from a cursor:

```
Declare @NumberOfRecords Integer
Set @NumberOfRecords = 100

Create Table #Tables(TableName SysName)
Declare @More Bit
Declare CTable Cursor Local Fast_Forward For Select Table_Name From Information_Schema.Tables Where Table_Type = 'Base Table'
Declare @CTableName SysName
Declare @SQL National Character Varying(4000)

Set @More = 1
Open CTable

While (@More = 1)
Begin
  Fetch Next From CTable Into @CTableName
  If (@@Fetch_Status != 0)
    Set @More = 0
  Else
  Begin
    Set @SQL = N'If (Select Count(*) From [' + @CTableName + ']) = ' + Cast(@NumberOfRecords As National Character Varying) + N' ' +
               N'Insert Into #Tables(TableName) Values(''' + @CTableName + N''')'
    Execute (@SQL)
  End
End

Close CTable
Deallocate CTable

Select * From #Tables
Drop Table #Tables
```